# fitvids is adding padding-top to youtube video as inline important

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, youtube, fitvids

I'm using a youtube embed plugin via wordpress to insert youtube videos. They work fine on some pages, but in of my widget areas the plugin adds an inline element of `padding-top: 50%` to the div with a class of `'fluid-width-video-wrapper'`, which shifts my video down 50% of the way, leaving a large gap. The div doesn't exist though when I use it on other areas of my site.

The div structure goes: epyt-gallery > widescreen flex-video when there is no issue, but on my widget area it goes:
epyt-gallery > fluid-width-video-wrapper > widescreen flex-video.

Is there something I did wrong with this area? Is there a way to remove the inline style or div from the widget area? I'm not sure how to go about it since the plugin seems to be adding it.

The widget area is currently using a shortcode inside of a 'text' widget.
The plugin is called YouTube by EmbedPlus Team.

Comment: Can you add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @MauricioAriasOlave- It's currently happening on the blog pages of our site. Please take a look at https://clinicalinformationsciences.com/information-mastery-article/ to see the issue, on the right sidebar. Thanks!